# Build vNext missing tasks

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines

I'm currently working with TFS Build vNext.

I've seen lots of tutorials and I've found out that many vNext build tasks are missing in my Build vNext.  Tasks like "Publish build artifacts" or "Powershell on target machines" are not in my list of available tasks.

I've been looking for a solution or a way to upload the tasks to my TFS (if there is any), given that these tasks are public to download and extend but haven't found anything.

Does anyone know how can I have these tasks available? I'm running TFS 2015.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're using RC1. RC1 was an earlier iteration of the new build system and thus doesn't have a lot of the tasks that RC2 has.

There is a Node application in the GitHub repo for the build tasks for uploading tasks, but I haven't sat down and used it so I can't say for certain it will work.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/tree/master/TaskUploader

Comment: Yes. After updating to RC2 I got the missing tasks.  Thank you.